# Listen to orientation animation in Android

Tags: java, android

I need a way to check whether the orientation animation has finished completely. This is not related to onConfigurationChanged because that kicks in before the animation .Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is an `AnimationListener`:

```
final Animation animation = yourAnimation;
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // Animation has finished.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I know about the AnimationListener. The question is there a way to get an instance of the Lanscape to Portrait Orientation Animation. Which is system defined as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question. Unfortunately, I think you might be [out of luck](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12153520/905349) with what you're looking for.