# Disable effects on rotation screen android

Tags: android

I  am creating a Camera app.

When phone is rotated , I see a default android animation of screen rotation.
In camera app this animation does not look good.

How can I disable it programatically?

Comment: please show your `code`. We cannot help you without showing what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should force the screen orientation to portrait (or landscape) and handle rotation using accelerometer. I guess this is the only way to display a camera preview without recreating surfaces and other UI hickups. At least this is the way a default camera application handles rotation.

Then You can add custom rotation animations to your icons, relayout UI, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since Api level 18 you can do this:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = activity.getWindow()
                .getAttributes();
lp.rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_CROSSFADE;
```

See [WindowManager.LayoutParams documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#rotationAnimation)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape) Answer (from Android Framework Engineer), the screen rotation animation work is done out of scope of an Application.

So, NO, there don't seems a way to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully checked on: Java - Android 9 (Pie) - Android Studio 4.1.3 - Huawei P10

For six months I could not solve this need. The problem was in the unassigned flag "FLAG_FULLSCREEN" in code.

First step MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); */ // If the animation still is, try applying it.
    setRotationAnimation(); 
  }

  private void setRotationAnimation() {
    int rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_JUMPCUT;
    Window win = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
    winParams.rotationAnimation = rotationAnimation;
    win.setAttributes(winParams); 
 }

  public void Button (View view) {
    // Connected to android:onClick="Button" in XML.
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Next step MainActivity2.java:

```
public class MainActivity2 {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    /* getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); */ // If the animation still is, try applying it.
     setRotationAnimation(); 
   }

   private void setRotationAnimation() {
     int rotationAnimation = WindowManager.LayoutParams.ROTATION_ANIMATION_JUMPCUT;
     Window win = getWindow();
     WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
     winParams.rotationAnimation = rotationAnimation;
     win.setAttributes(winParams); 
   }

   public void Button (View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
   }
 }
```

Next step styles.xml:

```
 <resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   </style>
 </resources>
```

Simple things I understood: You must first anywhere start "setRotationAnimation()", before running activity2. When start activity2 you have to run in it "setRotationAnimation()". Works incorrectly.