# Avoid animation on orientation change to prevent ugly view stretching

Tags: android, animation, orientation-changes

### Introduction

My app should show a button that fills up the entire screen, but stays quadratic. I have accomplished that by referencing orientation-dependend dimen-values:

#### activity_main.xml

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fartbutton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fartbuttonWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fartbuttonHeight"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/sel_fart_button"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"/>
```

#### dimens-land/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fartbuttonWidth">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
    <dimen name="fartbuttonHeight">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
</resources>
```

#### dimens-port/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="fartbuttonWidth">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
    <dimen name="fartbuttonHeight">@dimen/wrap_content</dimen>
</resources>
```

[image] [image]

This was to ensure, that the `ImageButton` couldn't be pressed by touching the top of the screen, which would be far away from the image.
I since have implemented a check to ensure, that the button only reacts to presses on an opaque part of the image, ignoring touch on transparent areas. There this might not be as necessary anymore.

I also have programmed a widget on which I think I'm not able to change the layout programmatically. That's why solutions to the following problem that work entirely within the XML-files are prefered.

### The problem

I know that when I change the orientation of my device, the activity gets completely destroyed and recreated. In that process, the OS transitions between the two states with a nice (and wanted) rotation. However, it also stretches and fades the two buttons in an ugly way, as shown in the image.

[image]

I assume that it tries to respect the `match_parent` attribute of the old button and therefore stretches the image to match the full new width.

I already searched for how to disable activity transitions and tried to find an existing solution to my problem. Sadly, since most people would like to *add* custom animation to orientation changes or disable the rotation animation *completely*, my searches for this problem haven't been successfull.

Is there an easy way to circumvent this ugly stretching? Would a shared element activity transition work? What solutions come to you mind? :)

### Edits

#### First edit

Seems like setting all dimensions to `wrap_content` (even that of the `FrameLayout`) and fixing the button's dimension to 200dp don't work. Now I assume that the OS is simply taking a screenshot and stretching it to the new landscape proportions or vice versa.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? The new button is fully opaque and rotates just fine. It probably would be enough to disable the fading animation.

#### Second edit

I now noticed this behaviour in **all** the apps on my phone. I could not find a way to tell Android to just not do it... :(

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a standard behaviour that cannot be turned off... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Rahil2952](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736283/avoid-animation-on-orientation-change-to-prevent-ugly-view-stretching#comment59176194_35736283) pointed out referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12153520/3287963), there seems to be no solution. It is a "feature" Android provides, over which the programmer does not have easy control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a square FrameLayout by subclassing FrameLayout and overriding onMeasure:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

Then wrap your button in this FrameLayout in your layout.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work. I implemented `SquareFrameLayout` that extends `FrameLayout` and inside its `onMeasure()` I called `super.onMeasure()` with the smallest width as both parameters. I then put the `ImageButton` inside the `SquareFrameLayout` in XML. But still, it does the stretching. :(