# How to rotate all icons only

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, screen-rotation

In my android application, i want to rotate the screen portrait mode to landscape mode but i want to rotate the icons only, below I have attached sample images.

[image: Potrait mode]

[image: Landscape mode]

[Sample video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eG0e_KvyNhk&feature=youtu.be)

How can I do this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eG0e_KvyNhk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Better you should attach your screen.

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847080/android-retaining-camera-preview-on-orientation-change-while-other-views-can-ro