# freeze the orientation of a single view in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a camera view where the camera image and 3D stuff is rendered and on top is a transparent view with all the UI elements. Now i want to freeze the orientation of the camera view and let only the UI View rotate if there is a orientation change of the device.

How can I do that?

I already tried it the other way around to set the android:screenOrientation of the activity to landscape and rotate the UI View with view.setRotation(degree) when I detect a orientation change. This worked very good but its possible that the android status Bar is on the wrong side.

Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847080/android-retaining-camera-preview-on-orientation-change-while-other-views-can-ro)  & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly)

Comment: The links don't really solve this kind of problem. Does that mean there is no solution for this problem?