# Android: How to rotate the keyboard 180 degrees programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, rotation, keyboard

I'm working on an app where two players will play on the same phone in front of each other and I rotate many things 180 degrees each turn. (few things should not rotate)

The players might use the keyboard to type some text when needed, so I need to also rotate the keyboard 180 degrees and put it in the upper side of the screen if it's the other player's turn.

How can I do that programmatically to the keyboard only?

I should also do the same when I start developing the iOS app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);` for rotating the screen by 180 degrees and when you want to switch back to the original view use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: Is it possible to cancel the rotation animation ? This seems promising.. it even fixes a shadows problem as I didn't know how to make the shadows be above the views when elevated.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.. here's how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape/36828791#36828791

Comment: the reverse orientation works fine on API 21 but not on API 19 !!?

Comment: This gentleman here says that this feature was introduced in API level 9 http://stackoverflow.com/a/31926128/5355581

One other thing I read on the thread was somebody mentioning to add `android:configChanges = "orientation"` to the manifest file.

Comment: I added the configChanges but still not working on LG G2 (API 19) but working fine on Samsung S5 (API 21)!

Comment: May be you can first trying getting the root view of your activity by calling
`View view = (View)findViewById(R.id.content)` and then use `view.setRotation(180)`. Try this and let me know if this works.

Comment: It now works as the screenrotation was disabled on G2! Now I need to force the rotation even if the autorotation is disabled !