# How to force orientation change without getting black screen

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a button that forces a orientation change form portrait to landscape.

When calling `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

the orientation changed to landscape but i get a black screen for a second.

When i rotate the device by hand i dont get this black screen. i get a nice rotating animation.

Is there a way to force rotation without this black screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957772/disable-default-animation-from-portrait-to-landscape

Comment: Have look [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html)

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Comment: No, some devices just turn black when rotating and some dont